# Behavior of IN with empty subquery

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to select every customer from the table `KNA1` which does not have any entry in table `KNBK`.

So I made a select query which should do this for me:

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_kn_nr FOR kna1-kunnr.
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_kn_okd FOR kna1-ktokd.

SELECT * FROM kna1
    INTO TABLE @DATA(ls_kna1)
    WHERE kunnr IN @s_kn_nr
      AND ktokd IN @s_kn_okd
      and kunnr not in ( select kunnr from knbk where kunnr in @s_kr_nr )
```

Now my question is, does the select query handle empty subselects in the same way as empty select options and just select everything?

Comment: Isn't it easy to test yourself before asking? From the result you get, maybe you can refine your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: no.

Such a subquery returns a set and `IN` functions here exactly as the mathematical operation of belonging to set or no. So if the set is empty then no element belongs to it.